# Using BeautifulSoup without Installation

Tags: python, import, module, installation, beautifulsoup

I have BeautifulSoup 3.x installed on my Linux work machine. I want to use BeautifulSoup 4.x because it supports utf-16. I don't want to remove BeautifulSoup 3.x from the computer. I just want to add bf4. Which files should I download from the website and how do I import them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to install different versions of certain Python libraries on the same system. You should use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for this. It allows you to create new virtual Python environments, with their own site-packages, and install packages in them. You can then have different projects running on the same machine all with different requirements. [Here](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/25/getting-started-with-virtualenv-isolated-python-environments/)'s an easy tutorial.